# ASP.net for Front end designers. where to begin?

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, frontend, designer

I'm a front end designer that has been working with PHP, WordPress, joomla, open cart and the likes.

Most may be familiar with the workflow. We start off planning > wireframes > PSD/fireworks. dish out HTML/CSS, and push it into WordPress as a theme or whichever framework we use.

Now I'm tasked to work with ASP.net. I hear about master pages (and how awesome they are), .ASPx files, 
ASP-MVC. etc etc. My question is, where do I begin? how will my workflow change as a front end designer?

are there any recommended reading, books, or video tutorials, that I can start off with as a front end designer? How I could work with master pages, and prepare my files for the backend dev teams. or how I could convert my HTMLs to .ASPx file.

I don't need to know how to code it entirely I am looking to learn how the workflow is like. and If I'm tied down to visual studio express. (I would very much love to stick to Sublime text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is plenty of free material on the web, but I always prefer to grab a good book.

ASP.NET is just a way of develop applications that generates HTML per request, so since it seems you already got web technologies, you should now understand how ASP.NET works.

You should start by learning .NET basics, for example by reading the first ten chapters of : [Beginning C# Object-Oriented Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430249358), and also the chapter 12.

Then move to an ASP.NET MVC specific book like: [Pro ASP.NET MVC 5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430265299)